# loading Laravel 5 RESTFul API for app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Question: Load the data from the persistent storage via a REST API.

how do i do this using laravel, i am new to laravel please bear with me if this is a stupid question. What does this mean? I have used this piece of code to generate my restAPI

```
 $search = $request->input('term');

    $results = array();

    $queries = DB::table('events')
        ->where('headline', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('zip', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->take(10)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id,
            'headline' => $query->headline,
            'address' => $query->address,
            'zipcode' => $query->zip,
            'long' => $query->longitude,
            'lat' => $query->latitude
        ];
    }
    return Response::json($results);
```

i don't know where to go ask. I have tried doing all this in the controller.

Please someone correct me if i'm wrong i tried:

```
    public function index()
{
   $events = Event::all(); 
   return view('event.show')->with('events', $events);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. do you want a json response, or a html response? what does `return view('event.show')` have to do with `return Response::json($results);`? have you tried `dd($results)` before the return to check you have db results? Do you have any errors that are showing? What's the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not compeletely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you're using it as a Restful API, then there's no point to return the view since you only want the JSON outputted.

Possible solution: Create a route that will print out the JSON from the controller. You can read more about the routes from Laravel documentation.

Comment: ok this is it, i given a test project to develop and it says "The list of events is loaded from persistent storage over a REST API." this is my problem what do i do

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: Yet again, your question is not understandable. Post your. code, output and if relevant, errors. We will not write your code for you, we only help fixing it.